# How to show that following equation for probability is true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have three random variables $W,X,Y$(all of them can have only non-negative values). I want to find the probability of following event $$E=A\cap[B \cup C]$$ where $A$ is the event that $X\leq g$, $B$ is the event that $W \leq g$ and $C$ is the event that $X+Y\leq g$. In one of the paper it is written that the probability of $E$ is as follows $$P(E)=P(X\leq g)\left[\left(1-P(W\leq g))(1-P(X+Y\leq g)\right)+P(X+Y\leq g)\right]$$
$g$ is some positive constant. I do not understand how this can be true. Please help me in proving this. Thanks in advance.

My Attempt:

In my attempt I obtain following expression for $P(E)$ $$P(E)=P(X\leq g)P(W\leq g)+P(X\leq g|X+Y\leq g)P(X+Y\leq g)[1-P(W\leq g)]$$I used the following identities from set theory $$A\cap[B \cup C]=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C )$$
$$A\cap B=B\cap A$$ $$A\cap A=A$$

Do you think my expression is right?

Comment: No, that doesn't look okay at all.  Events $A,C$ are not independent; indeed $A\supset C$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp many thanks for your comment. I added my attempt and my expression in the edited post. Do you think my expression is right or is it wrong too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GrahamKemp as you mentioned in your comment that $A$ and $C$ are not independent. But I also checked for independence case (by replacing $C$ to be event $Y+Z\leq g$ ($Z$ being the independent variable) instead of $X+Y\leq g$) even then the result of $P(E)$ does not matches with the second equation in my post.

Comment: Note that $C\subseteq A$ hence $E$ is the disjoint union $$E=(A\cap B)\cup(B^c\cap C)$$ If $X$, $Y$ and $W$ are independent, this yields $$P(E)=P(X\leqslant g)P(W\leqslant g)+(1-P(W\leqslant g))P(X+Y\leqslant g)$$ What is your source?

Comment: @Did very very nice explanation. Your expression perfectly matches with my expression since $P(X\leq g|X+Y\leq g)=1$ and hence the second expression is not right in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that: $A\cap(B\cup C) = A\cap((B\cap C^\complement)\cup C)$

Now, because $X\leq g$ whenever $X+Y\leq g$ then $A\supset C$, so $A\cap C=C$ and $\mathsf P(A\mid C)=1$.  These events are definitely not independent.

---

Let's use $A\equiv X\leq g, B\equiv W\leq g, C\equiv Y\leq g$, with $W, X,Y$ independent continuous positive valued random variables  .  Then having ensured the events are independent, we obtain:

$$\mathsf P[A\cap(B\cup C)] = \mathsf P[A\cap ((B\cap C^\complement)\cup C)]
\\ = \mathsf P(A)~\Big(\mathsf P(B)~\big(1-\mathsf P(C)\big)+\mathsf P(C)\Big)\\\\ = \mathsf P(X\leq g)~\Big(\mathsf P(W\leq g)~\big(1-\mathsf P(Y\leq g)\big)+\mathsf P(Y\leq g)\Big)$$

In the original setup, we would use conditional probabilies (though still assuming, $W,X$ are independent):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P[A\cap(B\cup C)] ~=~& {\mathsf P(X\leq g)~\Big(\mathsf P(W\leq g)~\big(1-\mathsf P(X+Y\leq g\mid X\leq g)\big)+\mathsf P(X+Y\leq g\mid X\leq g)\Big)}\\[3ex] =~& {\mathsf P(X\leq g\mid X+Y> g)~\mathsf P(W\leq g)~\mathsf P(X+Y>g)+\mathsf P(X+Y\leq g)}\end{align}$$